# How can I upload a csv file into Wordpress?

Tags: uploads

I have some customers in my site.
My ERP system has customers along with their price reduction level.
I extracted from my ERP the list of customers' Tax IDs and price reductions levels and I want to upload it in a custom table in Wordpress.
Any idea how to automate that?

Comment: This sounds more like an SQL question than a WordPress question

Comment: Please provide more details about that file, how you're imagining your UI, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really clear on what you want to do, but there are several CSV import plugins. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=csv

But if you need to link the imported data to specific, existing posts, then it is more of an MySQL question and not purely WordPress.

Comment: He wants to put data from a csv inside a non wordpress DB table, it's a pure SQL question

Comment: Good idea, I ll use http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-csv-to-database/
Thanks!